# CSV import codeigniter with different array

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

Currently doing a project that requires me to import a data from CSV file into database, here is the data sample of the file:

```
|   id_attendance   |   name   |   date   |  time   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|        001        |   lily   |01.01.2018|  07:00  |
|        002        |  thomas  |01.01.2018|  07:02  |
|        003        |   lily   |01.01.2018|  19:00  |
|        004        |  thomas  |01.01.2018|  19:02  |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Meanwhile i need those data to be imported into this kind of table

```
|   id_attendance   |   name   |   date   |  time_in  |  time_out  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|        001        |   lily   |01.01.2018|  07:00    |   19.00    |
|        002        |  thomas  |01.01.2018|  07:02    |   19.02    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This requires me to automatically seperate the time fields into time_in and time_out. So far i already do the csv importing, here's my code

**importcsv_m.php** model

```
function importCSV()
{
    $count=0;
    $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
    while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024))
    {
        $count++;
        if($count == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        for($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++)
        {
            $insert_csv = array();
            $insert_csv['id_attendance'] = $csv_line[0];
            $insert_csv['name'] = $csv_line[1];
            $insert_csv['date'] = $csv_line[2];
            $insert_csv['time'] = $csv_line[3];
        }
        $i++;
        $data = array(
            'id_attendance' => $insert_csv['id_attendance'] ,
            'name' => $insert_csv['name'],
            'date' => $insert_csv['date'],
            'time' => $insert_csv['time'],
           );
        $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('attendance', $data);

    }       
    fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
    $data['success']="success";
}
```

But its only importing the data without seperating the time (no time_in and time_out)

I was wondering if i can import an array and divide it into two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created some code which tries to match the begining and end of each shift.  This works by looking for a matching start record and then adds in data for the end time.  If no matching start record is found, then it stores this data (assuming this is the start record).  Once the end record is found, the start record is removed from `$attendancies` as the next record may be a new shift...

```
function importCSV()
{
    $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
    // Ignore header line
    $header = fgetcsv($fp);
    // Array to store the partial records
    $attendancies = [];
    while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp))
    {
        // Key to identify first part of record (Name and date)
        $key = $csv_line[1]."/".$csv_line[2];
        if ( isset($attendancies[$key]) ){
            $start = $attendancies[$key];
            // Extract data from first part of record and add in end date from current row
            $data = array(
                'id_attendance' => $start[0] ,
                'name' => $start[1],
                'date' => $start[2],
                'time_in' => $start[3],
                'time_out' => $csv_line[3],
            );
            $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('attendance', $data);
            // Remove partial record
            unset($attendancies[$key]);
        }
        else    {
            // Store partial record
            $attendancies[$key] = $csv_line;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
    $data['success']="success";
}
```

Comment: Hey i actually got a lil problem here. i tried to import another file that contains another data but it says "duplicate entry '0' for key 'primary'" i wonder why it keeps inserting 0 values into the table every time i try to import a new csv file

Comment: It may be easier to ask another question with the specific data that your having problems with and the code which your using.

Comment: Actually i used your code, and it says duplicate on my 2nd import, that's why i asked you through the comment section

Comment: As this code just summarises the csv, it depends on what the key is and what is in the data file.  So in the csv, what is the data which is causing the problem (a specific example would help)?